# Eficiência do Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

Galera, eu tenho uma dúvida, e não estou achando nada a respeito na internet, eu estou fazendo uma aplicação para um cliente e estou usando o firebase, por ser um servidor do google eu acredito que ele vai aguentar o alto volume de usuarios, alguém pode me confirmar se o firebase realmente pode segurar um grande volume de usuarios? (utilizaremos a versão blaze), acreditamos q o volume deve ser algo entorno de 2.000 usuarios ativos simultaneamente pois se trata de um app para um site de animes que já é bem conhecido

Comment: Duvido que tenha 2000 usuários ativos simultaneamente, as pessoas tem ilusões sobre isso. Raríssimos os sites que tem isso, Mas se tiver seria melhor uma equipe mais experiente lidar com isso, ñ é tendo ver com pessoas aleatórias na internet que fará isso dar certo.

Comment: a pergunta não foi essa '-' , foi se o firebase aguenta o volume de usuarios ou não, leia novamente e reformule sua resposta, obrigado :)

Comment: @HiranJúnior Honestamente achei sua pergunta um pouco fora do escopo, o pessoal aqui aproveita o espaço para resolver problemas específicos com o foco maior em programação resolução de problemas pontuais, sua dúvida poderia ser respondida lendo a documentação do Firebase.

Comment: @Mr_Ghost a maioria das perguntas que tem aqui podem ser resolvidas lendo a documentação, o problema é q as vezes o entendimento fica vago, como é o caso da do firebase, eu n entendi bem os limites que ele chega :) , se não quer responder, ou não tem oq responder n precisa ue, só passar pra proxima pergunta, tenha uma boa tarde, e não quis ser grosseiro na minha mensagem caso tenha parecido isso.

Comment: @Mr_Ghost concordo, mas não é sair enchendo de negatividade (-1) as perguntas de usuários novos, ou com respostas que põe em dúvida a capacidade de desenvolvimento deles, que vai fazer com que o SOpt melhore. Muita gente tem preconceito com o site por isso (embora eu discorde de quem pensa assim).

Comment: Julio Henrique Até hoje não deixei nenhum voto negativo, pra mim tem que ter um motivo mt grande para isso, deixo meu like pra vcs porque acredito que estamos na mesma linha de pensamento. @HiranJúnior só expressei minha opinião dando um toque de como eu acho que o pessoal aqui encara as perguntas, no intuito do ajudar sempre.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase possui diversos serviços, se você está se referindo ao Realtime Database, serviço de banco de dados em tempo real, de acordo com [essas informações de planos](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?hl=pt-br).

> Plano Spark (Gratuito): Até 100 conexões simultâneas
>
> Plano Flame: Até 100 mil conexões simultâneas
>
> Plano Blaze: Até 100 mil conexões simultâneas por banco

Então, com certeza o firebase não teria qualquer problema para aguentar 2000 usuários simultâneos. Mas acho que não é um número para se preocupar agora, caso você não tenha lançado o seu app, pois dificilmente uma aplicação alcançaria essa marca de forma rápida.

**Edit:**

Em relação aos limites do Firestore, [este link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) possui maiores informações dos limites. E sobre as conexões simultâneas é citado:

> Conexões simultâneas máximas para clientes em dispositivos móveis/Web por banco de dados - 1.000.000

Comment: Eu estava me referindo ao firestore, eu sei q um app recém lançado n tem esse número de usuarios, mas eles são de um site relativamente conhecido e que esperam q maioria dos seus usuarios utilizem o app, será que o firestore aguentaria esse volume de requisições?

Comment: @HiranJúnior quanto ao firestore, também não terá problemas com certeza. Neste link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas, é citado 'Conexões simultâneas máximas para clientes em dispositivos móveis/Web por banco de dados - 1.000.000'

Comment: Obrigado! Vou olhar agora mesmo

Comment: @HiranJúnior se respondeu a sua pergunta, marque a resposta como aceita :)